# Why is exec not running my jar file properly?

Tags: php, yii2

Im trying to launch a jar file with an UI but when i run my code the UI doesnt appear which probably means the jar its not running properly and i dont understand why because when i run the string in the cmd variable on the command line it works fine.

```
public function actionImport($id){

    $javaComand = 'C:/RobotToTestLink/ExecutableJars/uploadxpdl.jar ' . '0 ' . '4 ' . 'PFDemoSuite ' . '1';

    $cmd = 'java -jar ' . $javaComand;

    $response = exec($cmd);

    if($response !== null) {
        $caseFind = NodesHierarchy::find()
            ->where(['parent_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'cases' => $caseFind,
        ]);
    }else{
        print ("Failed loading .Jar File");
    }
}
```

Comment: That little `'` char you got there (at `$javaCommand = '"..."'` and who knows where else) means dont interpret escapes. But you have \\ enclosed which never become a single \      ...  Fix that. Test. And report back.

Comment: @GetSet stil not working, i edited the code

Comment: why are you concatenating `$javaCommand` like that? Why not use a single string? `$javaComand = 'C:/RobotToTestLink/ExecutableJars/uploadxpdl.jar 0 4 PFDemoSuite 1';`

Comment: Also, `c:/path/to/java`

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

1 - put uploadxpd1.jar in the same directory as your XController.php

2 - give the jar file all access rights

3 - use exec($cmd , $outputArr); // outputArr will containe all output from command